# php download file, reading problem

Tags: php, file, download

```
<?php
function saveFile($url, $filename) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}
$myFile = "images.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
$data = explode("\n", $theData);

$count = count($data);

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++) {

    saveFile($data[$i], basename($data[$i]));
}

?>
```

This is my code and every time i replace a dynamic file name it prints error

```
Warning: fopen(10017226314.jpg ) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\download\download.php on line 4
can't open file
```

What should be the cause? please help. Thanks

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Have you looked at `$filename`? I think you will find it does not contain a valid file name.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your fopen function parameter from `w` to `r+`

```
function saveFile($url, $filename) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $fh = **fopen($filename, 'r+')** or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}
```